# How to improve realm query so that it doesn't block the UI

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, electron, realm

Here's one of my query

```
async function getCatlogEntities (articleId) {
// fetch catalog entities
let catalogEntities = await realm.objects('catalogentity')

// stringify
catalogEntities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(catalogEntities))

// fetch taxanomies
let taxonomies = await publicRealm.objects('taxonomy')

// stringify
taxonomies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(taxonomies))

// fetch catalog article entities
let catalogArticleEntities = await realm.objects('catalogarticleentity')

// stringify
catalogArticleEntities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(catalogArticleEntities))
console.log('catalogEntities', catalogEntities)
// create the required response
const articleEntities = _.map(catalogEntities, entity => {
// find taxonomies
const findTaxonomy = .find(taxonomies, {id: entity.taxonomy_id})
entity.taxonomy = !.isEmpty(findTaxonomy) ? findTaxonomy : {}
console.log('present catalog entity', entity)
if (!.isEmpty(entity.article_entity)) {
entity.article_entity = _.filter(entity.article_entity, articleEntity => {
const findArticleEntity = _.find(catalogArticleEntities, {id: articleEntity})
console.log('findArticleEntity', findArticleEntity)
// filter out the entities if not found OR article id present and didn't matched with current article id
if (!.isEmpty(findArticleEntity) && ((articleId && findArticleEntity.article_id === articleId) || (!articleId))) return findArticleEntity
})
}
return entity
})
return articleEntities
}
```

Can I improve it in a way so that it doesn't block the UI thread?
I'm facing 7-8 seconds UI block when the data is too heavy or when we are making multiple queries and mapping them together(as Realm doesn't support joins(aggregation)).

Comment: The question is a bit broad - Realm is fast - very fast - queries we run are over a 2Gb dataset return results (almost) instantly. Without digging into the code, are you processing the returned data in some way? Are you casting the returned Results to arrays? If so, then the processing bottleneck is there and unrelated to Realm. That being said, it's often best practice to run cpu intensive tasks on background thread to leave the UI fluid. Also, while Realm doesn't 'join' there are many ways to accomplish that task, denormalizing your data is one option.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for replying. What do you mean by denormalizing the data. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Denormalizing data is a common practice in NoSQL databases; disk space is cheap so often times it makes sense to keep duplicates copies of data to allow for broader and faster queries. There's more to it but that's the general idea. Check out: [this one](https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/joins-via-denormalization-for-nosql-coders-part-2-materialized-views) and [another one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/denormalization-in-databases/) and probably my favorite [denormalizing is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)